# Is this normal c++ behavior? compiler zero initialize my class despite having a user defined constructor

Tags: c++

Let's me describe my problem. I've analyzed the following code generated with Visual Studio 2015 [Release] with OllyDbg and memset is called twice (once with 408 bytes, and latter with 400 bytes). Clearly the 408 bytes is the compiler doing a zero initialization on my class.

Why is this happening?

My mainclass has already a constructor which should get rid of the compiler generated constructor.

The funny thing is: If I remove the member "someotherclas sb" from the mainclass, m_buffer will only be set once (by me, with 400 bytes).

```
// ConsoleApplication.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

class someotherclas
{
public:
    int * ptr;
};

class mainclass
{
public:
    char m_buffer[400];
    someotherclas sb; //If I remove this, buffer will be memset once only (by me, in the constructor)
    int a;

    mainclass()
    {
        memset(m_buffer, 0x00, sizeof(m_buffer));
        a = 6;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * arr[])
{
    mainclass * buffer2 = new mainclass;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume buffer should be m_buffer in your mainclass?

Comment: I suspect that in the real code `new mainclass;` is actually `new mainclass();`.

Comment: @Goodies is right. buffer should be m_buffer, I made a mistake there which I've fixed already. Other than that, all the code is correct, and can be compiled without any other modification.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No, it's not. it's mainclass; Again, this is the real code. However, even if it was new mainclass(), as far as i know, it's not supposed to call the compiler generated constructor since I've defined one already.

Comment: It's happening because you are in a debug build.

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > SDL checks > No.

Comment: @StoryTeller I already specified  Visual Studio 2015 [Release].

Comment: `memset`ing class to `0` that way is very bad idea as it will overwrite also vtable which may lead to strange behaviours.

Comment: @haulth I think you are a bit confused. The memset 408 call was generated by the compiler, not by me. Clearly the compiler knows what it's doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this happens because [Security Development Lifecycle checks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx) are enabled for your project. Could you check the compiler options? If so, the following applies:

> When /sdl is enabled, the compiler ... Performs class member
>   initialization. Automatically initializes all class members to zero on
>   object instantiation (before the constructor runs). This helps prevent
>   the use of uninitialized data associated with class members that the
>   constructor does not explicitly initialize.

Comment: Is there a way to dodge it? without disabling it? Or should I disable it? – Jose 6 mins ago

Comment: @Jose, I don't know of a way to just disable zeroing without disabling all the security development lifecycle. If you want to disable the whole, go to project properties, in the tree control on the left expand Configuration Properties, then C/C++, then General and in the table on the right find "SDL checks" and set to "No (/sdl-)".